# How can I take-off drop shadow effect from a panel Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an [banner](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/jd94vttr/show) that act as an accordion.

[image]

As default, the bootstrap panel class come with drop-shadow effect.
I want to take off the shadow around my **panel-heading**, and also my **panel-body**. I've tried to override it by giving a class `no-shadow`

```
.noshadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Result, It still showing up. :(

Any helps / suggestions will be much appreciated

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/jd94vttr)

Comment: I don't see a drop-shadow, all I see is a border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a shadow. It is actually border on `panel` div.
See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jd94vttr/1/

Comment: You got it. How do I also take off from my panel-body also ?

Comment: Remove border-top: 1px solid #ddd; from .panel-body

Answer (score 1):

It's using `border`s and not `box-shadow`.  Updated your [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jd94vttr/2/).

```
/*--------- add this to override Bootstrap ----------*/
.panel {
    border: none;
}

.panel-default .panel-heading {
  /*border: 1px solid silver; --------- remove this line ----------*/
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;

}
```

Comment: I still want to have my border. I just want to take off the shadow.

Comment: @ihue As [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd94vttr/3/) or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/jd94vttr/4/)?

Comment: Thank-you. I see it nowl